# absence of PDF output

Tags: texshop, thesis

Started to write `main.tex` file for my master's thesis and could not get the pdf file. Any help please?

here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\title{
    {Wrting master thesis is a pain through the life}\\
    {\large University of Master Studies}\\
    {\includegraphics{university_logo.png}} 
}

\author{Python Buddha}
\date{Day Month Year}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

console prompts with following message:

```
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `\maketitle` between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to get a titlepage with the information you've input.